# Is isomorphism of algebras of matrices always witnessed by matrix similarity?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an algebra of matrices. Suppose $A$ is isomorphic to some other algebra of matrices $B$. Is it always the case that there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that the isomorphism can be expressed as $X\rightarrow SXS^{-1}$?

Comment: Not in this strict sense: let $A=\Bbb R$ and $B=\{\lambda I_n:\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$ where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking - in order for $S X S^{-1}$ to make sense I would think you would have to have $S \in A$, and then how would you have $S X S^{-1} \in B$?

Comment: Maybe something along these lines would be: let $k$ be a field, $V, W$ vector spaces over $k$ of finite dimension, and $\Phi : \operatorname{End}_k(V) \to \operatorname{End}_k(W)$ an isomorphism of $k$-algebras.  Then there exists an isomorphism of vector spaces $T : V \to W$ such that $\Phi(X) = T \circ X \circ T^{-1}$ for all $X$.  I think this statement should be true.